# In sematic UI the tab is not being responsive

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I have been designing using semantic UI but the problem i face is in using tabular menu. The square block at the side in the menu is not changing when i select another menu item .It is still remaining at the home page while the content in the segment changes. [Have a view at the documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html). Image-[Though i have clicked meal planner the square block denoting the menu item remain at home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibe0z.png)